# How to configure more than 1 plugin in one extension in typo3

Tags: typo3

ext_localconf.php code

```
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'ABC',
    'Soapi',
    [
        oneController::class => 'fetchTopUser',
    ],
    // non-cacheable actions
    [
        oneController::class => 'fetchTopUser',
    ]
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'ABC',
    'CategoryList',
    [
        secondController::class => 'list',
    ],
    // non-cacheable actions
    [
        secondController::class => 'list',
    ]
);
```

Throw error
(1/1) #1316104317 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Exception
The default controller for extension "ABC" and plugin "CategoryList" can not be determined. Please check for TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.

Comment: The configuration looks okay. Are you moving away from switchable controller actions in a flexform? Had this also, deleted the plugin content element and added a new one fixed the error. You can also run the console command cleanup:flexforms from lowlevel system extension which checks the configured flexforms with the stored values.

Answer (score 0):

Class names in TYPO3 are in UpperCamelCasing and try to put the complete class names with their namespaces.

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'ABC',
    'Soapi',
    [
        \Vendor\ExtensionName\Controller\OneController::class => 'fetchTopUser',
    ],
    // non-cacheable actions
    [
        \Vendor\ExtensionName\Controller\OneController::class => 'fetchTopUser',
    ]
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'ABC',
    'CategoryList',
    [
        \Vendor\ExtensionName\Controller\SecondController::class => 'list',
    ],
    // non-cacheable actions
    [
        \Vendor\ExtensionName\Controller\SecondController::class => 'list',
    ]
);
~
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Your Code looks Correct (apart from the missing Namespaces to the Classes.
i would suspect that one of two thing might be happening here:

1. the namespace does not resolve. please use fully Qualified namespaces. as suggested by Mohsin Khan
2. or you forgot to register the second plugin in `your_extension/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php` (`\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin`)

Comment: I have done both things, but the same error is occurs.